# R loops - iterate a list of strings, expand as function input

Tags: r, loops

I am a python person, and am having trouble working with a for loop.
I have a list representing the names of particular columns in a dataframe containing colums (Sample_Name_Column, ComparisonColumn, MeasureA, MeasureB, MeasureC, MeasureD) which I want to use for a linear mixed effects model (using the nlme library). So I wrote a simple loop to try and do that:

```
list <- c("MeasureA","MeasureB","MeasureC","MeasureD")
for (i in list){
  model = lme(i ~ ComparisonColumn, random=~1|Sample_Name_Column, 
  data=sampleDataSheet, method="REML")
}
```

but of course this fails.

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~i + ComparisonColumn + Sample_Name_Column,  :   variable lengths differ (found for 'ComparisonColumn')
```

The function lme doesn't expand the variable; is looking for a column i as the input. Yet other functions like print() or length() do. Odd.
Anyway, I've found some posts that use .asformula and reformulate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461725/variable-lengths-differ-in-r-linear-modelling-with-lme4) but I'm having an awful lot of trouble getting it working.

```
for (i in groupList) {
model = lme(as.formula(paste0(i, " ~ ComparisonColumn, random=~1|Sample_Name_Column")), data=sampleDataSheet, method="REML")
}
```

I get a little further (because the iterable has been correctly inserted):

```
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:1:26: unexpected ','
1: MeasureA ~ ComparisonColumn,
                               ^
```

but something is wrong here too.

I should add that running the model directly works:

```
model = lme(MeasureA ~ ComparisonColumn, random=~1|Sample_Name_Column, 
data=sampleDataSheet, method="REML")

Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: 
sampleDataSheet
Log-restricted-likelihood: -462.6646
Fixed: MeasureA ~ ComparisonColumn
(Intercept)      ComparisonColumnTreatmentA 
 0.81377249 -0.08312908 

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Sample_Name_Column
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:   0.1800545 0.5348801
Number of Observations: 564
Number of Groups: 16
```

I've gotten a bit of the way, but can some kind soul please help me out to finish it off?

thanks,
K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as.formula alone seems not fit to your need, beacause you ave two formulas.

Look at this example, and compare fm1 and fm2 results, it may help you :

```
fm1 <- lme(distance ~ age + Sex, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1)

params <- list(fixed = reformulate(c("age", "Sex"), response =  "distance"),
           random = reformulate("1"),
           data = Orthodont)

fm2 <- do.call(lme,params)
```

Comment: thanks. this seems to get me part of the way there, but behaviour of some functions is odd when I do this.. I'll post an answer below to illustrate.

Comment: I think it's not a big issue, because each model is a structured objet, from witch you can get any information you need, for example : `fm2$coefficients` will give you coefficients .. you can study the structure of the object with `str(fm2)` ... and so you can easily build a data.frame with just the information you need, and you can also add in this data.frame names for the data used ..

Comment: Another way is to force a little the ouptut object .. from my example you can compare `fm1` and `fm2` by `all.equal(fm1, fm2)` and see that the difference lies in the component `call`. So by modifying the `fm2$call` you may obtain the same output ..

Answer (score 0):

I think MrSmithGoesToWashington has got me almost there. The code I'm now using is:

```
library(lsmeans)
library(multcomp)
library(nlme)

groupList = c("MeasureA","MeasureB","MeasureC","MeasureD")

for (i in groupList){
 print(i)

 # following MrSmithGoesToWashington's example
 params = list(fixed = reformulate("ComparisonColumn", response = i), random = reformulate("1|Sample_Name_Column"), data = sampleDataSheet, method="REML")
 model = do.call(lme,params)

 anova.lme(model, type="sequential", adjustSigma = FALSE)
 posthoc = glht(model, linfct=mcp(ComparisonColumn="Tukey"))

 Multiple_Comparisons_of_Means = summary(posthoc, sampleDataSheet=adjusted("single-step"))

 print(Multiple_Comparisons_of_Means)
}
```

But there's some weirdness about how the data from sampleDataSheet is being interpreted.

Without looping, the model variable prints as:

```
> model
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: test 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: -2961.527
  Fixed: MeasureD ~ ComparisonColumn 
       (Intercept) ComparisonColumnNP 
      1.924292e+02       7.532103e-03 

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Sample_Name_Column
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    21.12601  45.3235

Number of Observations: 564
Number of Groups: 16
```

but in the loop, the way params is handled by the do.call function, the data frame prints in its entirety as a "structure"; it prints as (once it has iterated the loop to "MeasureD"):

```
> model
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: structure(list(Sample_Name_Column = structure(c(10L, 10L, 11L,  10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L,  10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L,  10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L,  11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L,  11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L,  11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L,  9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L,  9L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L,  12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L,  12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L,  13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,  13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,  13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L,  14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L,  14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L,  14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L,  15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L,  15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, .....), .Label = c("A.2",  "A.3", "A.4", "A.5",  "A.7", "A.4", "A.6", "A.8",  "B.10", "B.8", "B.9",  "B.3", "B.4", "B.5", "B.6",  "B.7"), class = "factor"), ComparisonColumn = structure(c(2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  .....), .Label = c("LP", "NP"), class = "factor"), MeasureA = c(0L,  1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,  0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,  0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, .....  0L, 1L, 0L), MeasureB = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L,  3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L,  0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L,  0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L,  0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L,  0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L,  2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L,  ..... 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MeasureC = c(3L,  3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L,  2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 3L,  4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L,  2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L,  0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L,  0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L,  1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L,  ..... 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L,  3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 0L, 0L), MeasureD = c(157L, 150L, 120L, 159L, 193L, 96L,  225L, 197L, 278L, 252L, 191L, 165L, 240L, 202L, 221L, 225L, 167L,  235L, 249L, 231L, 219L, 273L, 185L, 221L, 150L, 180L, 282L, 216L,  128L, 255L, 161L, 152L, 90L, 154L, 153L, 135L, 130L, 145L, 131L,  175L, 99L, 148L, 173L, 115L, 196L, 227L, 208L, 139L, 278L, 234L,  148L, 109L, 233L, 167L, 151L, 141L, 122L, 106L, 120L, 140L, 266L,  226L, 277L, 198L, 237L, 162L, 203L, 201L, 192L, 237L, 230L, 221L,  182L, 184L, 298L, 191L, 240L, 210L, 250L, 186L, 187L, 229L, 230L,  206L, 293L, 182L, 218L, 209L, 171L, 152L, 279L, 324L, 122L, 132L,  223L, 250L, 155L, 189L, 206L, 213L, 233L, 215L, 95L, 164L, 213L,  188L, 273L, 284L, 206L, 185L, 209L, 176L, 136L, 190L, 214L, 240L,  231L, 190L, 211L, 165L, 246L, 236L, 244L, 265L, 160L, 220L, 203L,  186L, 110L, 181L, 180L, 264L, 159L, 151L, 179L, 144L, 187L, 144L,  280L, 280L, 295L, 214L, 217L, 246L, 184L, 204L, 200L, 223L, 192L,  226L, 209L, 146L, 209L, 181L, 223L, 196L, 226L, 147L, 191L, 180L,  154L, 162L, 170L, 174L, 144L, 230L, 155L, 197L, 228L, 196L, 166L,  182L, 169L, 192L, 206L, 117L, 133L, 127L, 193L, 156L, 140L, 267L,  234L, 280L, 181L, 230L, 169L, 192L, 166L, 182L, 140L, 244L, 201L,  230L, 168L, 159L, 152L, 211L, 195L, 125L, ..... 202L, 295L, 188L, 103L, 104L,  168L, 229L, 210L, 163L, 228L, 231L, 143L, 164L)), .Names = c("Sample_Name_Column",  "ComparisonColumn", "MeasureA", "MeasureB", "MeasureC", "MeasureD" ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -564L)) 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: -2961.527
  Fixed: MeasureD ~ ComparisonColumn 
       (Intercept) ComparisonColumnNP 
      1.924292e+02       7.532103e-03 

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Sample_Name_Column
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    21.12601  45.3235

Number of Observations: 564
Number of Groups: 16
```

This has repercussions on the output of the multiple comparisons of means, which outputs the whole data frame rather than the dataFrame name. It's not a huge issue, but it's messy.

```
> summary(Multiple_Comparisons_of_Means)

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: lme.formula(fixed = MeasureD ~ ComparisonColumn, data = list(
    Sample_Name_Column = c(10L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), ComparisonColumn = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), MeasureA = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L), MeasureB = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L), MeasureC = c(3L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 
    1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    MeasureD = c(157L, 150L, 120L, 159L, 193L, 96L, 225L, 197L, 
    278L, 252L, 191L, 165L, 240L, 202L, 221L, 225L, 167L, 235L, 
    249L, 231L, 219L, 273L, 185L, 221L, 150L, 180L, 282L, 216L, 
    128L, 255L, 161L, 152L, 90L, 154L, 153L, 135L, 130L, 145L, 
    131L, 175L, 99L, 148L, 173L, 115L, 196L, 227L, 208L, 139L, 
    278L, 234L, 148L, 109L, 233L, 167L, 151L, 141L, 122L, 106L)), random = ~1 | Sample_Name_Column, 
    method = "REML")

Linear Hypotheses:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
NP - LP == 0  0.007532  11.238300   0.001    0.999
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Any ideas how to fix that? Otherwise it's working. Thanks.

Comment: I now understand that using something like: Multiple_Comparisons_of_Means$test$pvalues[1] will give me the information I need.